# passing function as argument in the function

Tags: c#

how to pass argument as function

Comment: Refer this link below already present in SO
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380198/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c

Answer (score 6):

You're probably looking for [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28VS.80%29.aspx).

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(int myInt, string myString);
public void FunctionToCall(int i, string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s + " [" + i.ToString() + "]");
}
public void MethodWithFunctionPointer(MyDelegate callback)
{
    callback(5, "The value is: ");
}
```

And then, to call it:

```
MethodWithFunctionPointer(FunctionToCall);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make argument as delegate, and call function with address of function which should match with delegates