# Questions on delegate functions in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm learning about C# and one of the areas that interested me were delegate functions.  The following code uses them to apply a function to each number in a range [start, limit[ before it is summed.  This is a fairly simple example for clarity.

```
// function passing a delegate function
public override void solveProblem() {
    int squareOfSum = (int) Math.Pow(Library.Math.sumRange(1, 101), 2);
    int sumOfSquares = Library.Math.sumRange(1, 101, new Func<double, double, double>(Math.Pow), 2);

    this.solution = (squareOfSum - sumOfSquares).ToString();
}

// function that accepts / uses delegate function
static public int sumRange(int start, int limit, Delegate operation, params object[] args) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int current = start; current < limit; current++) {
        // add the current number in the range as an arguement
        object[] newArgs = new object[args.Length + 1];
        newArgs[0] = current;
        args.CopyTo(newArgs, 1);

        // sum the result of the operation (delegate function)
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(operation.DynamicInvoke(newArgs));
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The specific questions I have are:

- Is it possible to use dynamic delegate functions (that accept a variable length list of parameters with unkown types) but force the delegate function to return a specific type?  With non-dynamic delegate functions you set a return type, but also have to set the number of parameters and their types.
- How much slower is using DynamicInvoke than using a non-dynamic delegate function?
- What is the best way to handle parameters than what I currently do (which is accept a list of other parameters and prepend any parameters the function that uses the delegate needs to add in)?
- Do I need to declare 'new Func(Math.Pow)' to pass in the power function, or is there a way to just pass Math.Pow (and have the return type and parameters be passed implicitly)?

I've looked at the C# docs and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380198/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c) to learn how to use delegate functions, I just want to learn more about them.

Thanks!

jtfairbank

Comment: lucisferre has a [nice article](http://lucisferre.net/2011/01/18/being-dynamically-typed-in-a-statically-typed-world/) on dynamic typing. C# is primarily a statically typed language. Trying to use dynamic features everywhere will be a painful experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use dynamic delegate functions (that accept a
>   variable length list of parameters with unkown types) but force the
>   delegate function to return a specific type? With non-dynamic delegate
>   functions you set a return type, but also have to set the number of
>   parameters and their types.

You don't "force" the function to return something. The function returns something or it doesn't return something. The function "forces" you to accept something :-) (or to ignore it)

You can call a dynamic delegate through the `DynamicInvoke` and then cast the return value to what you know your delegate returns (or you keep it as an `object`). I say "what you know your delegate returns" but the reality is a little more complex: for Value Types you have to cast the return value to precisely the type used as return value or you'll get `InvalidCastException`. For reference types you can use an interface or a base class of the object returned (with some exceptions for Nullable types)

> How much slower is using DynamicInvoke than using a non-dynamic delegate function?

I've tested a `void Do()` method (the most simple method possible, with no boxing for parameters) and the time difference was demential. Let's say 400x :-) On http://ideone.com/f34cj it's between 70x and 150x.

> Do I need to declare 'new Func(Math.Pow)' to pass in the power function, or is there a way to just pass Math.Pow (and have the return type and parameters be passed implicitly)?

Creating a new `Func`/`Action` delegate is the right path.

---

In general the right solution is not what you are doing. The right solution is do as LINQ does. For example:

```
int pow = 2;
Func<int, int> myFunc = p => (int)Math.Pow(p, pow);

var listOfNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);

var result = listOfNumbers.Sum(p => myFunc(p));
```

Now, you have a delegate (`myFunc`) that takes a number and returns the square of that number (and note that through "closures" it closes around `pow`) (if you don't know what a closure is, try putting that word in google with the words lambda function). A list of numbers as an `IEnumerable<int>` and you do the sum of these numbers "converted" by `myFunc`.

Answer (score 1):

Read on LINQ - usage of IEnumerable produces much more compact code.

I.e. combination of Enumrable.Range ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx ) and Enumerable.Aggregate ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx ) is exactly what you trying to achieve:

```
var sum = Enumerable.Range(start,limit).Aggregate((s, cur)=> s+cur);
var sumSq = Enumerable.Range(start,limit).Aggregate((s, cur)=> s+ cur * cur);
```

Comment: That's very interesting.  I was using this primarily to explore / learn about the Delegate functions, but thanks for giving me another area of C# to look at!