# Pass a bool Foo(params[]) as method Argument

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, invoke

There are times that a method needs to be run several times until it validates. In my case there are expressions like `bar.Name.Equals("John Doe")` which I want to run and run until this expression validates.

Something like:

```
bool succeeded = TryUntillOk(bar.Name.Equals("John Doe"), 15, 100);
```

where `TryUntillOk` would be a method that runs this expression 15 times with a sleep of 100ms between each call.

I read this [excellent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380198/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c) list of answers to similar issues but in my case there is no standar delegate that this `TryUntillOk` method would accept.

The title of the question is not constructive. Feel free to edit it :)

Comment: Would this be running in a separate thread? Otherwise there's not going to be any chance for the value to change.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett YES. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
bool TryRepeatedly(Func<bool> condition, int maxRepeats, TimeSpan repeatInterval)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < maxRepeats; ++i)
    {
        if (condition()) return true;
        Thread.Sleep(repeatInterval); // or your choice of waiting mechanism
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which would be invoked as follows:

```
bool succeeded = TryRepeatedly(() => bar.Name.Equals("John Doe"),
                               15,
                               TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
```

The only interesting part here is that you specify the condition as a `Func<bool>`, which is a delegate to a method that takes no parameters and returns a boolean. Lambda expression syntax allows you to trivially construct such a delegate at the call site.

Comment: It should probably be noted that this relies on something external (separate thread etc) causing the condition to eventually evaluate to true.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett sorry for not mentioning this. All this would be done in worker threads

Answer (score 1):

You have to adapt the invokation. @Jon's answer has lambda invoaction, this version separates the comparand from the delegate

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace test
{
    class something
    {
        public String Name;
    }

    class Program
    {
        private delegate bool TryableFunction(String s);

        private static bool TryUntillOk(TryableFunction f, String s, int howoften, int sleepms)
        {
            while (howoften-->0)
            {
                if (f(s)) return true;
                Thread.Sleep(sleepms);
            }
            return false;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            something bar=new something();

            bar.Name="Jane Doe";
            bool succeeded = TryUntillOk(bar.Name.Equals,"John Doe", 15, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("Succeeded with '{0}': {1}",bar.Name,succeeded);

            bar.Name="John Doe";
            succeeded = TryUntillOk(bar.Name.Equals,"John Doe", 15, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("Succeeded with '{0}': {1}",bar.Name,succeeded);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly this was my first attempt. Later I realized that there might be several methods to call, meaning that I'd had to declare so many delegates which is something I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it

```
delegate void d_name(string s);

d_name obj =new d_name(bar.Name.Equals);

bool succeeded = TryUntillOk(obj("John Doe"), 15, 100);

TryUntillOk(obj d,type parameter2,type parameter3 )
{
  //do your work
}
```