# Send any method as a parameter for the purposes of getting metadata

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to send a ***any*** method as a parameter? I need to do it for all kind of method, not caring about signatures and returns. Say something like this (bad code, just for the idea):

```
public class Foo
{
...
void TestMethod(DontKnowWhatToPutHere theDelegate) {}
...
}

...

foo.TestMethod(-foo.AnotherMethod(1,2)-);
foo.TestMethod(-foo.AnotherMethod("I don't care method signature nor returning type")-);
```

I tried with no success to do it with `Action` as parameter.

**What I need to do** is to send ***any*** method to a function, and then use reflection to get method name and parameters, so if there's another way you guys can figure out, I would gladly hear about it too.

Comment: Use a `string`. If you're going to inspect the class anyway, you don't have *that* much to gain by knowing that some methods by the desired name exist.

Comment: Hey Please have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380198/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c it is an exact replica of what you are asking I guess

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The compiler always has to be able to identify a specific delegate to convert to, and there's no single delegate type which is compatible with all method signatures. You can get a long way by using `Action`, `Action<T>`, `Action<T1, T2>` etc, then `Func<TResult>`, `Func<T1, TResult>` etc... but even that's going to fail when it comes to `out` and `ref` parameters. Additionally, there's overload resolution to consider.

Additionally, your syntax is passing the *result* of a method invocation, which isn't the same thing as passing a method in the first place. (That's ignoring the `-` prefix/suffix, which appears to be made-up syntax.)

What you *could* use is `Expression<Action>` and wrap the method call:

```
void TestMethod(Expression<Action> action)
{
    ...
}
```

Then:

```
foo.TestMethod(() => foo.AnotherMethod(1,2));
```

Within `TestMethod` you can then look into the expression tree to find out that it's a method call, work out the target, the parameters etc. See the [MSDN page on expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) for more information.

Comment: +1. Especially for `Expression` - pattern used in many unit test frameworks.

Comment: Great! This is good. Now I got `((MethodCallExpression)action.Body).Method.Name` and `((MethodCallExpression)action.Body).Method.GetParameters()` that gives me what I need, except by the `AnotherMethod` parameters values. I've researched and found that I can't get parameters values using reflection, is there any workaround in order to get this/these parameters? (other than sending `object[] parameters` as a `TestMethod` parameter)

Comment: @ChuckNorris: You can get the arguments from the `MethodCallExpression.Arguments` property. (I assume you want to know the arguments you're calling it with, not just the parameter types declared by the method.)

Answer (score 4):

You can pass [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) object

```
void TestMethod(MethodInfo methodInfo, object methodObject, object[] parameters)
{
    methodInfo.Invoke(methodObject, parameters);
}
```

Comment: Does `MethodInfo` refer to methods, or method groups?

Comment: The actual method (if you're referring to overrides/overloads). They know what type they were declared on, and the parameters/types involved.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair That would make this answer useless then.

Comment: This involves finding the MethodInfo by reflection though - I believe the OP basically wants to avoid having to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo
{
   void TestMethod(Action<int, int> theDelegate) {}
   void TestMethod(Action<string> theDelegate) {}
}

foo.TestMethod(() => foo.AnotherMethod(1,2));
foo.TestMethod(() => foo.AnotherMethod("I don't care method signature nor returning type"));
```

Comment: Any method, I don't care about method signature and returning type. This solution would make me write a TestMethod override for every each possible method.

Comment: Yea overloading is required here, but you can have a GenericTestMethod doing common task in it and is called by each overloaded method. This way you don't have replicate your TestMethod logic.